# When I type space bar in edittext searchbox while searching, search results displaying nothing in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am fetching names from the webservices using xml parsing. I am using edittextbox for searching names. Now, When I type the first letter of the first name or last name, It perfectly retrieves and shows the names list.

But, when I type the first name and I left a space before typing the lastname, the names list displays nothing. But Actually, the related search results should  display according to the typed first name.

The code I am using:

HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.put("Name",String.valueOf(XMLfuncts.getValue(e, "Name")));

mylist.add(map);

adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ViewList.this, mylist,R.layout.userdetails_row, new String[] { "Name",
                                                                                                            "Moblie", "CompName" }, new int[] {
                                                                                                            R.id.TextViewName, R.id.number,
                                                                                                            R.id.compname });

```
            searchname.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                                      int count) {

                                          // onTextChanged
                                 }

                                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                                      int after) {
                                            // beforeTextChanged

                                }

                                 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                                            // afterTextChanged


                            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

                                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }

                    });
```

The thing which I need is the search results should remain active eventhough I type the space between firstname  and lastname in the edittextbox.

Comment: Thank you so much..! Let me checkit out I think it will work..! Thanks again..!

Comment: Hi gtumca-MAC, this answer is not working. Still I am facing the same problem. Please give me some other solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
map.put("Name",String.valueOf(XMLfuncts.getValue(e, "Name")));
```

Try by replacing this line as

```
String str = String.valueOf(XMLfuncts.getValue(e, "Name"));
str =str.trim(); // will remove space between names
map.put("Name",str);
```

Hope this will work..!

Comment: Hi gtumca-MAC, this answer is not working. Still I am facing the same problem. Please give me some other solution.  –

Comment: According to your coding the first name and lastname get concat, but still when I type the firstname and when I type a spacebar, the search results displays nothing..!

Comment: The new coding which I am using is as follow:                                                                                                                             String str = String.valueOf(XMLfuncts.getValue(e, "Name"));
String input = str.replace(" ", "");
String str_value = input.trim(); // will remove space between names
Log.i(this.toString(), "Name"+str_value);
map.put("Name",str);